# Java Memory Model and reordering operation

Tags: java, memory-barriers, java-memory-model

The my question is addressed to the post:
https://shipilev.net/blog/2014/safe-public-construction/

```
public class UnsafeDCLFactory {
  private Singleton instance;

  public Singleton get() {
    if (instance == null) {  // read 1, check 1
      synchronized (this) {
        if (instance == null) { // read 2, check 2
          instance = new Singleton(); // store
        }
      }
    }
    return instance; // read 3
  }
}
```

And, it is written:

> Notice that we do several reads of instance in this code, and at least "read 1" and "read 3" are the reads without any
>   synchronization — that is, those reads are racy. One of the intents of
>   the Java Memory Model is to allow reorderings for ordinary reads,
>   otherwise the performance costs would be prohibitive.
>   Specification-wise, as mentioned in happens-before consistency rules,
>   a read action can observe the unordered write via the race. This is
>   decided for each read action, regardless what other actions have
>   already read the same location. In our example, that means that even
>   though "read 1" could read non-null instance, the code then moves on
>   to returning it, then it does another racy read, and it can read a
>   null instance, which would be returned!

I cannot understand it. I agree that compiler obviously can reorder memory operations. But, doing it, the compiler **has to preserve the behaviuor of the original program from the one-thread's point view.**

In the above example, the `read 1` read non-null. The `read 3` read null. It means that `read 3` was reorderd by the compiler and read the `instance` in the precedence to `read 1` ( We can skip CPU reordering, because the post raises Java Memory Model).

But, on my eye `read 3` cannot overtook `read 1` because of  store operation- I mean `instance = new Singleton();`

After all, there is data dependency, it means that the compiler cannot reorder instruction `read 3` with `store` because it changing the meaning of the program ( even one-threaded). The compiler also cannot change order the `read 1` because it has to precede the `store`. Otherwise, the semantic of one-threaded program is different.

Therefore, the order must be: `read 1 -> store -> read 3`

What do you think about it?

P.S. What does it mean to publish something? Especially, what does it mean to publish somegthing unsafely?

---

It is an re-answer to the @Aleksey Shipilev's answer.

> Let me say this again -- failure to construct the example does not disprove the rule.

Yes, it is obvious.

> And Java Memory Model allows returning null on the second read.

I agree with that as well. I don't claim that it doesn't allow. ( It is possible because of data race- yes,  they are evil). I claim that `read 3` cannot overtake `read 1`. I know you are right, but I would like to understand that. I still claim that Java compiler cannot generate a such bytecode that `read 3` take over `read 1`. I see `read3` can read `null` because of data race, but I cannot imagine how it is possible that `read 1` read non-null and `read 3` read null while `read 3` cannot overtake `read 1` because of data dependency.

(We don't consider here memory ordering on the hardware (CPU) level)

Comment: "the compiler has to preserve the behaviuor of the original program from the one-thread's point view" - what makes you say that?

Comment: Also, if read 1 reads a non-null value, this thread **does not perform a store**. There is no requirement to maintain ordering relative to operations that don't happen. Some other thread probably performed a store, but without synchronization, the ordering requirements relative to that other thread's store are quite lax.

Comment: " this thread does not perform a store", yes, but when a compiler compiles the code it cannot know whether `instance` is null or not.

Comment: Doesn't matter. For example, Java is allowed to perform a speculative load of `instance` for the return value first, planning to throw that value away and reload it if the thread performs a store to `instance`, then perform another load of `instance` to compare to `null`, see that the second load loaded a non-null value, and use the first loaded value as the return value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But, doing it, the compiler has to preserve the behaviuor of the
>   original program from the one-thread's point view.

Nope. It has to preserve the requirements of the language spec. In this case, JMM. If some transformation is legal under JMM, then it can be performed. "One-thread's point of view" is not a normative language, specification is.

And Java Memory Model **allows** returning `null` on the second read. If you cannot construct the actual transformation that does it, it does not mean such transformation is not possible. Let me say this again -- failure to construct the example does *not* disprove the rule. Now you can see the example transformation in ["Benign Data Races are Resilient"](https://shipilev.net/blog/2016/close-encounters-of-jmm-kind/#wishful-benign-is-resilient), and also read this paragraph there:

> This may appear counter-intuitive: if we read null from instance, we
>   take a corrective action with storing new instance, and that’s it.
>   Indeed, if we have the intervening store to instance, we cannot see
>   the default value, and we can only see that store (since it
>   happens-before us in all conforming executions where first read
>   returned null), or the store from the other thread (which is not null,
>   just a different object). But the interesting behavior unfolds when we
>   don’t read null from the instance on the first read. No intervening
>   store takes place. The second read tries to read again, and being racy
>   as it is, may read null. Ouch.

That is to say, you can easily transform the program to expose the path without the intervening write, and there trivial read reordering gives the "counter-intuitive" result. Bytecode is not the only "transformation" the program is amenable to. The link above outlines the compiler transformation that *exposes the code path without the data dependency* on store. I.e. these two programs are subtly different:

```
// Case 1
Object o1 = instance;
instance = new Object();
Object o2 = instance;

// Case 2
Object o1 = instance;
if (o1 == null)
  instance = new Object();
Object o2 = instance;
```

In "Case 2", there *is* a path that avoids the store to `instance` -- because program has two paths now, due to a branch -- optimizing transformations can expose it.

This is a contrived example of what could go wrong. In real programs, the control and data flows are much more complicated, and optimizing transformations are allowed to (and will eventually) yield similar result, because they operate on the set of derived rules like "no synchronization, no data dependencies -- free to move stuff around", after a metric ton of transformations that expose interesting behaviors.

**Data races are evil.**

Comment: thanks for your attention. I edited my post with extra question to your answer. I didn't ask you in the comment to make it more clear.

Comment: Have you read the link I posted? I summed it up in my revised answer.

Comment: oh, yeah, I didnt' notice that you gave a link.  I am going to read it , thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Consider a class

```
class Foo { String bar = "qux"; }
```

When reading `Foo::bar`, you would always expect it to return the string `"qux"`. A constructor call is however not atomic. It can rather be split into two segments:

```
Foo foo = <init> Foo;
foo.bar = "qux";
```

With unsafe publication, a thread might have published `Foo` but not its value of `bar` from its local memory. As reading a `volatile` field requires the synchronization of all memory, this problem is resolved by the above pattern.

Answer (score 1):

There is an easy way to sidestep most of this:

```
public enum SafeSingleton {
  INSTANCE;
}
```

Comment: @Gilgamesz, Andreas is correct, the `instance == null` check is not thread safe. The enum Singleton is thread safe and about as simple as you can get.